# Angular - Owl carousel: items with multiple logos and rows

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm working on an **owl-carousel** that displays different logos (*currently 43*). You can scroll through them by clicking on the navigation arrows or on the dots. I've been instructed to display **6 columns of logos in 3 rows** for each dot. You can see what this looks like in the images below

[image]

Unfortunately, as you can see, my **logo 43** ends up alone, right in the middle, when I click on the last dot. And that doesn't suit my managers. Indeed, they would like me to achieve one of the following two solutions:

- Ensure that if my last item has less than 3 logos, it's automatically displayed at the far right of the carousel (**see image 3**)
- Make all the items readjust before a loop ends (before my last group appears on the screen). So that all the groups always have 3 logos and no two are ever the same (I don't know if I'm making myself clear, but I've diagrammed this in **image 4**)

[image]

But I have absolutely no idea how to go about it. Do you have any ideas and can you please help me?

I made an example on Stackblitz with mock data to make it more understandable: [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owl-carousel2-angular13-qzx9ye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz exapmle with mock data? Then I will help you with possible solutions.

Comment: @Flo Indeed, it will be more convenient. Her is the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owl-carousel2-angular13-qzx9ye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Many thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem. Is hard to solve because you need 3 rows. Image 3 is impossible because you can scroll right and the carousel jumps back to point one. So the Logo 43 will be always stay alone in random place by navigating. Image 4 needs recreation any time you navigate to the last group. Image 3 can be possible if you disable "loop"